# How can I reduce the entry and exit animation speed of BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am not sure is this can be acheived using **setEnterTransition()** and **setExitTransition()** methods.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I think I got the answer:

I can use `getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations()` method to achieve the same.

Comment: Would be better if you show your example for over here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using StyleAnimation

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null)
        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
}
```

slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="3000"/> <!--Define duration here-->
</set>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="5000"/> <!--Define duration here-->
</set>
```